# A timer in python that not rules

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a code in python for a countdown timer with the time and tkinter libraries, but not rules. The cronometer part only shows the spin.get

Windows 10 and python 3, running on sublime text

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*
import time
window=Tk()
window.title('Programa')
window.geometry('300x500')
window.resizable(True, True)
window.config(bg='dark grey')
f=Frame(window, width=300, height=500)
f.pack()
f.config(bg='dark grey')
var =IntVar()
var.set(30)
spin = Spinbox(f, from_=0, to=100, width=5, bg=('dark grey'), 
textvariable=var)
spin.place(x=125, y=100)
text1=Label(f, text='Tiempo de ejercicio:', bg=('dark grey'))
text1.place(x=5, y=100)
def codigo():
#here is when not works, on the for i in range
    f2=Frame(f, width=300, height=500)
    f2.pack()
    f2.config(bg='dark grey')
    text2=Label(f, text=spin.get(), font=('Arial Bold', 90), bg=('dark grey'))
    text2.place(x=80, y=200)
    for i in range((spin.get),1,1)
    time.sleep(1)
btn1 = tk.Button(f, text = 'Empezar', command = codigo, bg=('dark grey'))
btn1.pack()
btn1.place(x=150, y=150)

window.mainloop()
```

The cronometer part only shows the spin.get, but i need the time go down

Comment: Don't you get a syntax error with your code at the `for` loop?

Comment: Now I see, 'ts:
   
 for i in range(spin.get(),1,1):
        time.sleep(1)

but not work's

Comment: There's no colon at the end of the line. And when you fix that, you will need to indent the next line.

Comment: it also does not work,it only show the spin.get, but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is another function which counts down and gets itself called one second later:

```
# keep code as you have it before codigo
text2 = None
def timer():
    text2['text'] = str(timer.current)
    timer.current = timer.current - 1
    if timer.current >= 0:
        f.after(1000, timer)
def codigo():

    global text2
    f2=Frame(f, width=300, height=500)
    f2.pack()
    f2.config(bg='dark grey')
    text2=Label(f, text=spin.get(), font=('Arial Bold', 90), bg=('dark grey'))
    text2.place(x=80, y=200)
    timer.current = int(spin.get())
    timer()
```

Comment: A trick I've used is: `timer.current` which attaches a variable directly to the function itself. This works here because its only `codigo` which uses it and `timer` is not used again before the count down has finished.